# VIM/Python: visualmode/mode detection

Tags: vim

```
function! Delete() range
python3 << EOF
import vim

vim.command('let x = visualmode()')
mode = vim.eval('x')

EOF
endfunction
```

I'm not able to detect 'mode' properly in vim (xterm). It can't switch between 'visual' 'normal' - i get 'n' or '^V' always, regardless of what mode i'm actually in. I invoke the function like so:

```
 :map <kDel> :call Delete()<CR>
:imap <kDel> <Esc>l:call Delete()<CR>
:vmap <kDel> <Esc>:call Delete()<CR>
```

How exactly are these functions used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simplified version of your function (please use testable examples):

```
function! Delete() range
    python << EOF
    import vim

    print vim.eval('visualmode()')

    EOF
endfunction
```

does exactly what it is supposed to do:

- if the last visual mode was plain *visual* mode, it echoes `v`,
- if the last visual mode was *visual-line* mode, it echoes `V`,
- if the last visual mode was plain *visual-block* mode, it echoes `^V`.

Of course, you would do the following in your real function:

```
mode = vim.eval('visualmode()')
```

What, *exactly*, do you expect and what, *exactly*, are you trying to achieve?

--- edit ---

From `:help visualmode()`, emphasis mine:

> The result is a String, which describes ***the last*** Visual mode used in the current buffer.

So it is obvious that `visualmode()` can't be used to know the *current* mode. The right function is `mode()`.

From `:help mode()`, emphasis mine:

> This is useful in the 'statusline' option or when used
>   with remote_expr() ***In most other places it always returns
>   "c" or "n".***

So using straight `mode()` in most contexts will be useless, as demonstrated by the mappings below that all put you in normal mode before calling `mode()` so you always get `n`.

```
function! Delete() range
    python << EOF
    import vim

    print vim.eval('mode()')

    EOF
endfunction

nmap <key> :call Delete()<CR>         --> n
imap <key> <Esc>:call Delete()<CR>    --> n
xmap <key> <Esc>:call Delete()<CR>    --> n
```

For `mode()` to return the value you want, you need to be in an *expression* context which allows you to *evaluate* stuff without leaving the current mode:

```
nmap <expr> <key> Delete()            --> n
imap <expr> <key> Delete()            --> i
xmap <expr> <key> Delete()            --> v, V or ^V
```

Comment: 'It can't switch between 'visual' AND 'normal' - i get 'n' or '^V' always, regardless of what mode I'm actually in'. Eg: I select a block of text (block-visual) and hit <kDel>, the function is invoked and debug-print shows ^V being returned; then i just tap the <kDel> key and i still debug-print ^V (visual-block isn't selected). 'mode' behaves in a similar fashion: If i highlight a block (visual-block-mode) and hit <kDel> i get an 'n'!

Comment: This is from the manual: "mode([expr])    Return a string that indicates the current mode." >>"n       Normal" >>  CTRL-V  Visual blockwise

Comment: AFTER block highlighting the text and invoking the function etc it works okay and prints ^V - THEN when i hit <kDel> with NOTHING highlighted it should print 'n' - it doesn't.

Comment: I need to be able to distinguish between 'insert' mode, visual block mode, command mode and modify delete's action accordingly.

Comment: ah! wrks! :) thank you *purrs a happy purr* pfft your edit was 9 minutes ago, my typing was an hour ago in response to your request for more info: "What, exactly, do you expect and what, exactly, are you trying to achieve?"

Comment: Another case where `mode()` doesn't default to `n` is in an operator-pending mapping (`omap`).